# How To Redirect Page After Updating SQL Based on Values Updated?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

So I use CodeIgniter and have this condition: If I update a row with `status == 'no'` it should be redirected to `home.php` and if I update a row with `status == 'yes'` it should be redirected to `add.php`

How can I do it? Anyone can help me? Thanks before

Comment: What are you actually looking for ? how to redirect ? or how to build the logic for yes and no ?

Comment: the logic for yes and no based on values updated sir @ArifSajal

Comment: While @ArifSajal answer is correct and one way of doing things, we could better help you if you showed some of your current code to make a more accurate answer on your specific logic.

Comment: I have edited my ans.

Comment: @Alex yes Arif's answer is very good, and I haven't do any codes yet because I want to know what is a basic logic to do this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you get a value for gender

```
$gender = $this->input->post('gender');
```

i have to check if the gender was male or female, if gender was female than i have to redirect to female section if not than i have to redirect to male section

```
if($gender == 'm')
{
    $this->db->update('table_name',array('field'=>'Male'));
    redirect('male_section');
}
elseif($gender == 'f')
{
    $this->db->update('table_name',array('field'=>'Female'));
    redirect('male_section');
}
```

That's it. This is the easiest code how i can make you understand.

Comment: Seems very clear dude, So the idea is check the input field's value, then do the update based on its value. I will try it, thanks

Answer (score -1):

just use :

```
header("location:yourpage.php");
```